# How to return a value from Void Function?

Tags: c

I have that one void function like this,

```
void Charge(float p[15][11], int cantPol){
    cantPol = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){        
       for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
           &p[i][j]
       }     
       cantPol++;
    }
    cantPol;
}
```

Function call
`Charge(p, cantPol)`

I can return trought value 'cantPol' using pointers as i did with the matrix?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and tell us how you'd like to call the `Charge` function. BTW: what's the purpose of `&p[i][j]`? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: The function is equivalent to `printf("\n\n15\n");`. What is its purpose?

Comment: The real purpose of the function is read one file with 15 or less polynomials of 10 degree's and passing trougth value, using a void function, the matrix with the polynomials, and the cant of polynomials in that file. The ampersan works to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is two type of passage in function : passage by value and passage by variable.

cantPol here is **passed by value** that mean It will not be changed after the finish up of the function.
Basically because it will only create a copy of the variable and change the copy not the variable.

Now when you assign a pointer you will tell the compiler this is the address of the variable (*cantPol) means the memory @ of cantPol.

So here inside the function, it gonna go to the right @ and change the value inside : the value of the variable cantPol. And here you can recover the expected new value of cantPol. It means cantPol is **passed by variable**.

You should omit the last line

```
cantPol;
```

it hase no sense.

So you should change your void into:

```
  void Charge(float p[15][11], int *cantPol)
    {
        *cantPol = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){        
           for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
               &p[i][j]
           }     
           (*cantPol)++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("%i\n",*cantPol);
    }
```

Without change anything inside the function.

Another way to return cantPol is to transform the void into int funct means you will return the calculated value. Note that here no use of pointer but still way to get the calculated value.

```
int  Charge(float p[15][11], int cantPol)
{
   cantPol = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){        
       for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
           &p[i][j]
       }     
       cantPol++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("%i\n",cantPol);

    return cantPol;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is working, i'm dont statement thar variable with pointer

Comment: Read carefully your `Charge(float p[15][11], int *cantPol)` function. You forgot a `*` at 2 different places

Comment: There is still another `*` missing.

Comment: @ Gaston Martinez please note the changes. Like @ Jabberwocky said i forgot a * at 2 diff passes. Now i correct it.

Comment: @ Jabberwocky  hh yes sorry again. I have focused on the call that i copy past without pay attention sorry again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184454/discussion-between-jabberwocky-and-dina-taklit).

Comment: @Gaston Martinez i did correct the answer keeping on concideration what he said Jabberwocky. Please check it again. Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

> Can I return trought value 'cantPol' using pointers as i did with the matrix?

In general yes, but with the current function declaration you can't.
`cantPol` is an integer that is passed "by value". Whatever you do within your function does not have any effect when the function is left.

If you want to use `cantPol` to return a value, you must change the parameter list to use a pointer instead:

```
void Charge(float p[15][11], int *cantPol)
```

Then you can assign new values to `*cantPol` which will be visible at the caller

You also need to adapt your function call. Simply passing an integer as before will not work. You need to pass the address of your integer variable.

Comment: Yes, i try to do that, but get a error from the compiler. (_ warning: passing argument 2 of 'Charge' makes pointer from integer without a cast_) that error happens in the function call ´Charge(p, cantPol)´. 
Maybe is the call wrong??

Comment: Yes, your call is wrong. See my update. You cannot change the way a function works and still use the old function call.

Answer (score -1):

Change it from a `void` function to an `int`. The last line should read `return cantPol;`

Comment: This is not "using pointers as i did with the matrix" which was the point of the question

Comment: Sorry. In the line `void Charge( ...` change `int cantPol` to `int *cantPol` and in the main body of the function replace `cantPol` with `(*cantPol)`. Delete the last line. Changes the function Charge makes to `cantPol` will also take place in the caller